# C Linked List allways returns null

Tags: c, list, file

I'm trying to do a project to check if the word in a list is repeated, but it seens AuxLista allways returns temp-palavra as null?

```html
void AuxLista(Lista *L, char tmp_word) {
    if (!L) return;
    Lista *temp = L;

    printf("\n");

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->palavra == tmp_word){
            printf("%s Está repetida. ", temp->palavra);
        }
        printf("TESTE %s", temp->palavra);
        temp = temp->prox;
    }
}

Lista *criarLista(char *word){

    Lista *result = malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    AuxLista(result, word);

    result->palavra = word;
    result->prox = NULL;
    if (result->NOCORRENCIAS == NULL) result->NOCORRENCIAS = 1;
    else result->NOCORRENCIAS = result->NOCORRENCIAS + 1;

    return result;
}
```

- List item

Answer (score 1):

Your `AuxLista` function is `void` -- it doesn't return anything.

Also, be aware that the result of `malloc()` is uninitialized memory. If you don't set each byte to a value, then you must assume that the byte has the worst possible value it could have. You might consider using `calloc` or passing the memory to `memset` to initialize everything to `0`.

And you should check that `malloc` didn't return NULL, which it will do if you aren't looking.

Finally, don't use `NULL` to mean `0`. Your `NOCORRENCIAS` appears to be an integer (because you set it to `1`) which means you would normally be checking it against `0` rather than `NULL`. But that whole `if/else` appears to be wasted -- you could probably just do `result->NOCORRENCIAS += 1` and handle the zero/non-zero cases the same.

Comment: What i meant was that temp->palavra is allways null dispite it should have something. Apreciatte the help!

Comment: Again: the result of `malloc` is uninitialized memory. You are calling `AuxLista` before you provide any values to the memory.